# Socket.io call ack on connect event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there any way too utilize the ack argument on the connect event in Node.js? Something like this:

```
//client.js
socket.on('connect', (data) => {
  console.log(data); // I want to print 'lol' here
});

//server.js
io.on('connect', (socket, ack) => {
  ack('lol'); // TypeError: ack is not a function
});
```

Reference for ack: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the socket.connect() or socket.open() methods take an ack argument.  I generally will emit a 'connected' event from the server once a connection from the client is established.  You can receive this emission and add your behavior as needed.

**server.js**

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('connected');
});
```

**client.js**

```
socket.on('connected', function() {
  console.log('Connected');
});
```

Comment: There really isn't a reason to send a `connected` event to the client.  The client already has such an event.  The main reason to send a message at connection time is if you want to send data to the client immediately upon connection.  You don't need to tell the client that it is now connected - the socket.io framework already does that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific ack data that you can send for the connect event.  You can just `.emit()` a message to the client when the server receives the connect.

```
//client.js
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('client connected');
});

socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
  console.log(data); // 'lol'
});

//server.js
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  // send welcome message upon connect
  socket.emit('welcome', 'lol');
});
```